# python3のpsycopg2でutf-8の文字列をinsertすると文字化けする

Tags: python, postgresql

python3上のpsycopg2でutf-8の日本語文字列をtypeがtextのカラムにinsertすると文字化けします
どうすればいいのでしょうか?

databaseのEncodingは`UTF8`になっています

psqlからinsertした場合には文字化けは起こらないのですが、下記のようにpsycopg2でinsertすると文字化けします

```
cursor.execute("insert into test_table (utf8_text) value (%(utf8_text)s);", 
{"utf8_text": "こんにちは"})
```

下記のissueがあるようなのですが、この問題を回避するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?
https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/331

ちなみにPython3.5.2, Postgresql: 9.5.3, psycopg2: 2.6.2です

Answer (score -2):

日本語のテキスト前に`u`を入れると回避できるかと思われますがいかがでしょうか。

```
cursor.execute("insert into test_table (utf8_text) value (%(utf8_text)s);", 
{"utf8_text": u"こんにちは"})
```